# Joomla Categories in URL

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm trying to build a sitestructure that pretty much contains of a homepage and then two sites. I was trying to do this with categories but didn't seem to be successful, as the category isn't really showing in the url.

I'm trying to do this:

```
    Home (www.mysite.com)
       - Subsite 1 -> Menu (www.mysite.com/subsite1)
       - Subsite 2 -> Menu (www.mysite.com/subsite2)
```

Then i would like to have all articles assigned to either category "subsite 1" or "subsite 2" and create urls such as

```
    www.mysite.com/subsite1/(other categories)/article.html
```

Is it possible to realize this over the category? So that every article that someone adds to a category will be displayed like this?

Also, is it possible to display the Menu of Subsite 1 on EVERY artical of that category? (same thing with subsite 2)

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible:
In (Joomla) admin control panel, under `global configuration->site` you can enable the option `Search Engine Friendly URLs` under `SEO Settings` section.

If you enable SEF and install `Subsite 1` in a folder called `Subsite1` under apache root folder, and suppose your category is called `category1`, you'll be able to access your pages like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Subsite1/category1/<article-id>-<article-alias>
```

Pay close attention to the `-` between the article-id to the article-alias.

Comment: it's supposed to be one site and one backand as there are articals that both subsites use

Comment: In that case, use `category` as your base line for a subsite. You can configure `.htaccess` to redirect all calls for a specific domain/subdomain to a specific folder!

Comment: but the entire joomla site is in ONE folder

Comment: i've been trying to this with menus and a top level entry (the categories) and then only displaying them from level 2
but it doesn't work because the category (if more than one menu) then is displayed as a number instaed of the actual alias

Comment: The way to do it is to install two instances of Joomla, each one under a different folder - both folders should be under the main root folder (usually it's `/var/www/html/`). The you configure `.htaccess` under the root folder to direct the traffic to the folders with respect to the subdomains